# Zend_Validate's isValid() method, and the $_POST array

Tags: zend-framework, zend-validate

In a book on the Zend Framework I have come across a custom validator for unique email addresses.  The validator extends Zend_Validate_Abstract and therefore implements the isValid() interface.

In the interface the method signature is isValid($value).  In the concrete class, it's isValid($value, $context = null).

The author explains that the $context variable contains the $_POST array and he relies on values from the array in the method's implementation.  When I try to reproduce the code, however, my $context array is null.  Furthermore, I am unable to find any reference to $context in the Zend_Validation reference guide, or to passing in the $_POST values.

Has anyone else come across this?

BTW, the book is Zend Framework 1.8 Web Application Development by Keith Pope.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$context` array is passed when used with `Zend_Form_Element::isValid` method

Here is the snippet from `Zend_Form_Element::isValid` that is passing the `$_POST` as `$context` which is normally received from `Zend_Form::isValid`

```
            foreach ($value as $val) {
                if (!$validator->isValid($val, $context)) {
                    $result = false;
                    if ($this->_hasErrorMessages()) {
                        $messages = $this->_getErrorMessages();
                        $errors   = $messages;
                    } else {
                        $messages = array_merge($messages, $validator->getMessages());
                        $errors   = array_merge($errors,   $validator->getErrors());
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the documentation for Zend_Validate is incomplete.

This behavior is described in the manual for [Zend_Form_Element](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html) (ctl-f "Validation Context")